# static Xml Deserialization into a generic list in C# not working

Tags: c#, xml, static

So I have an XML file that I am trying to deserialize into a generic list, but no matter what I do, the List stays empty. I went threw the first ~10 Stack overflow questions that popped up about this, but I haven't figured it out yet.

When the program starts up, I call FishContainer.Load(), the file reader reads the file just fine, but nothing goes in the List.

**Xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FishContainer>
    <Fishies>
        <Fish Name = "test">
            <WaterType>salt</WaterType>
            <Price>1</Price>
            <Size>1</Size>
            <Aggression>1</Aggression>
        </Fish>
        <Fish Name = "test2">
            <WaterType>fresh</WaterType>
            <Price>12</Price>
            <Size>12</Size>
            <Aggression>12</Aggression>
        </Fish>
    </Fishies>
</FishContainer>
```

**Fish Container**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public static class FishContainer {
[XmlArray("Fishies"), XmlArrayItem("Fish")]
public static List<FishData> fishs = new List<FishData>();

public static void Load() {
    TextAsset _xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("fishdata");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<FishData>), new XmlRootAttribute("FishContainer"));
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(_xml.text);
    fishs = (List<FishData>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();

    Debug.Log(fishs.Count);
}

public static FishData GetFishAttributeByName(string name) {
    foreach(FishData f in fishs) {
        if(f.Name.Equals(name))
            return f;
    }
    return null; //throw
}
}
```

**Fish Data**

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class FishData {
[XmlAttribute("Name")] public string Name;
[XmlElement("WaterType")] public string WaterType;
[XmlElement("Price")] public int Price;
[XmlElement("Size")] public int Size;
[XmlElement("Aggression")] public int Aggression;

public override string ToString() {
    return Name + " " + WaterType + " " + Price + " " + Size + " " + Aggression;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're deserialising the type `List<FishData>`, but that's not what your XML file contains at the top level, it's a `FishContainer`, which in turn has a property of `List<FishData>` inside it.

Also, you can't deserialise to a static property or class, so you need to remove the static modifiers in `FishContainer` for the class and property at least. Here is how I would correct `FishContainer`:

```
public class FishContainer
{
    [XmlArray("Fishies"), XmlArrayItem("Fish")]
    public List<FishData> Fishes { get; set; }

    public static FishContainer Load(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FishContainer), new XmlRootAttribute("FishContainer"));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            return (FishContainer)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public FishData GetFishAttributeByName(string name)
    {
        return Fishes
                .SingleOrDefault(fish => fish.Name.Equals(name));
    }
}
```

As a rule, personally I try only to use `static` methods or properties if they don't change or hold the state of something. You can call this as follows;

```
var fishContainer = FishContainer.Load(_xml);
Console.WriteLine("I have {0} fishes", fishContainer.Fishes.Count);
```

EDIT: however, as you want it to be statically available with only a single instance of `FishContainer`, you could do something like this:

```
public class FishContainer
{
    private static FishContainer _instance;

    [XmlArray("Fishies"), XmlArrayItem("Fish")]
    public List<FishData> Fishes { get; set; }

    public static void Load(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FishContainer), new XmlRootAttribute("FishContainer"));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            _instance = (FishContainer)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    public static FishData GetFishAttributeByName(string name)
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("FishContainer has not been loaded");

        return 
            _instance
            .Fishes
            .SingleOrDefault(fish => fish.Name.Equals(name));
    }
}
```

.. and call like this:

```
FishContainer.Load(_xml);
var someFish = FishContainer.GetFishAttributeByName("test");
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I had it working similar to that earlier, but in my program I'm going to be calling the FishData list from multiple objects. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. Ideally I want to say "FishContainer.GetFishByName("blah")", but now I have to keep track of which object made the list in the first place.

Comment: @user318798, if you need it statically available and there is only ever a single instance of `FishContainer` you want available, see latest edit.

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much! Also, nice touch with the lambda expression, I didn't even think of it.